# Function of pseudocode applying it at an array

Tags: algorithms, computer-science

The following pseudocode is given:

```
partition(A,p,r){
  x<-A[r]
  i<-p-1
  for j<-p to r-1
       if A[j]<=x then
          i<-i+1
          swap(A[i],A[j])
  swap(A[i+1],A[r])
  return i+1
```

I have to describe the function of  `partition`  at the array: $A= \langle 13, 19, 9, 5, 12, 8, 7, 4, 21, 2, 6, 11 \rangle$.

I found the following:

[image]

So the final form of the array is:

[image]

But how could I describe the function of  `partition`  at the array?

Comment: Are you looking for a black-box description of _what_ you get out of the algorithm, or a description of _how_ it does it?

Comment: @HenningMakholm I have understood what we get out of the algorithm.. I wanted to know how I could explain how it does it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps it would help to formulate a loop invariant:

> After each iteration of the loop, all elements with indices in $[p,i]$ are less than or equal to $x$, and those with indices in $(i,j]$ are larger than $x$. Those in $(j,r)$ have not been looked at yet.

Then body of the loop then just does what is necessary to maintain the loop invariant after $j$ has increased by one.

---

By the way, your "final form" looks like you haven't yet swapped the `12` in place between the two lists.

Comment: So can I just mention the invariant without proving it?
$$$$
Also I am asked to describe the function partition at the array 
 $A =  \langle 13, 19, 9, 5, 12, 8, 7, 4, 21, 2, 6, 11 \rangle$.
$$$$
So do I have to mention all the commands that are executed?

Comment: @evinda: I'm not sure how to interpret that requirement. Perhaps the people who ask you to describe the algorithm want proofs; perhaps they are after an intuitive understanding; perhaps they want a step-by-step trace of everything for that particular input. You will have to clear that up with _them_, rather than rely on the guesses of random people on the internet.

Comment: Henning Thanks for your help!!! Could you make also take a look at this? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1178804/execution-time-of-function